# Reading file with pandas read csv is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

All the column data is going inside the "index" column

the header starts from row number 7

```
'''
 index      mfg    legalId    resellerName   resellerCountry
(SONICWALL',' ','HEXAPAGE','FRANCE')                
(SONICWALL',' ','SEXTANT BTS LLC','UNITED STATES')              
(SONICWALL',' ','New Vision Networks, Inc.','UNITED STATES')
'''
```

All the values are inside index column, i want those values to come under specified column respectively
Specified columns are

> mfg, legalId, resellerName, resellerCountry

Below is the code which i have written, please help me how to do this

```
df2=pd.read_csv(data, header=6, keep_default_na=False, sep=',', delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

Comment: I am no expert but this seems like a weird format for CSV:
The index should be seperated by commas,
The commas in the values are in quotes and there are brackets around your rows which probably causes them to be read as tuples?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @sophros i'm not getting any errors

Comment: @n4321d the problem is i cannot read the index column since it is creating that column internally which is creating a problem

Answer (score 0):

if your .csv file already has columns as first row then remove header=6 argument and let it infer which is default.
[image]

If you keep "index" column in csv file then with header='infer' dataframe will look like below table which is not aligned with respect to data. As data is shifted to left because data does not have index values mentioned

```
+----+-----------+-------+--------------------------+----------------+-------------------+
|    | index     | mfg   | legalId                  | resellerName   | resellerCountry   |
+====+===========+=======+==========================+================+===================+
|  0 | SONICWALL |       | HEXAPAGE                 | FRANCE         |                   |
+----+-----------+-------+--------------------------+----------------+-------------------+
|  1 | SONICWALL |       | SEXTANT BTS LLC          | UNITED STATES  |                   |
+----+-----------+-------+--------------------------+----------------+-------------------+
|  2 | SONICWALL |       | New Vision Networks Inc. | UNITED STATES  |                   |
+----+-----------+-------+--------------------------+----------------+-------------------+
```

you can remove "index" column from .csv file and reset_index on dataframe by:

```
df2.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
```

and data will be:

```
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------+-------------------+
|    |   index | mfg       | legalId   | resellerName             | resellerCountry   |
+====+=========+===========+===========+==========================+===================+
|  0 |       0 | SONICWALL |           | HEXAPAGE                 | FRANCE            |
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------+-------------------+
|  1 |       1 | SONICWALL |           | SEXTANT BTS LLC          | UNITED STATES     |
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------+-------------------+
|  2 |       2 | SONICWALL |           | New Vision Networks Inc. | UNITED STATES     |
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Hi @Poonam Adhav, thanks for your reply but there is no index column in the file, the column starts with 'mfg' which is at row number 7, so i think we should use header=6, the problem is when i'm reading the file, internally it is creating a index column and putting all my data into it like this (SONICWALL',' ','HEXAPAGE','FRANCE') but the notable point is there is no such problem in .xlsx or .xls only it is creating problem in .csv, the above solution is not helping. please help

Comment: I didn't get that "mfg" is at row number 7? how come, isn't  it in first row?

Comment: No @Poonam Adhav the column starts from row number 7 and from there only we have to read  the file.

Comment: I tired with header=6 and without "index" in .csv file. It is working fine. It didn't put all data in index column.